# How to keep newline of text from string array item in android?

Tags: android, arrays, string

I am developing an android app that has long texts.
I put them in a string-array.One item looks something like this

```html
<string-array name="data">
  <item>
    Bangladesh has been aptly described as a new state in an ancient land. 
   
    Much has been written about the past glory of Bangladesh, notably in old records like the evidence of Pliny and Periplus of the Erythrean Sea (first century AD).
    
    They include the Chinese travellers Fa-hien (fourth century AD), Hue-an-tsung (seventh century), Ma-hoen and Fei-shin (fifteenth century), Ibne Batuta (fourteenth century) from Africa, Nicola Kanti (fifteenth century) and Ceasar the Frederik (sixteenth century) from Venice, Verthema, an Italian in the sixteenth century, Barbosa and Sebastin Manric (sixteenth century) from Portugal, Travernier and Bernier from France (seventeenth century) and Queen Elizabeth-the First's ambassador Ralf Fish. 
    
    Etymologically, the word Bangladesh is derived from the cognate Vanga which was first mentioned in Aitarey Aranyaka, a Hindu scripture composed between 500 BC and 500 AD.
    
    
  </item>  
 </string-array>
```

When i get the text in my Activity class and put in a textview i looks like this:

> Bangladesh has been aptly described as a new state in an ancient land. 
>   Much has been written about the past glory of Bangladesh, notably in old records like the evidence of Pliny and Periplus of the Erythrean Sea (first century AD).They include the Chinese travellers Fa-hien (fourth century AD), Hue-an-tsung (seventh century), Ma-hoen and Fei-shin (fifteenth century), Ibne Batuta (fourteenth century) from Africa, Nicola Kanti (fifteenth century) and Ceasar the Frederik (sixteenth century) from Venice, Verthema, an Italian in the sixteenth century, Barbosa and Sebastin Manric (sixteenth century) from Portugal, Travernier and Bernier from France (seventeenth century) and Queen Elizabeth-the First's ambassador Ralf Fish. Etymologically, the word Bangladesh is derived from the cognate Vanga which was first mentioned in Aitarey Aranyaka, a Hindu scripture composed between 500 BC and 500 AD.

So all the new lines are gone.I can add newline by putting "\n" after a line 
but i have a huge set of such data. So manually adding them will be difficult.

Is there any way i can keep the same formation of my text when i get them by calling getResources.getString-array(data)?
I am not using any database for this project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can place html text in strings.xml file, this way:

```
 <string name="text">
    <![CDATA[
        </br>Bangladesh has been aptly described as a new state in an ancient land.</br></br>

        Much has been written about the past glory of Bangladesh, notably in old records like the evidence of Pliny and Periplus of the Erythrean Sea (first century AD).</br></br>

        They include the Chinese travellers Fa-hien (fourth century AD), Hue-an-tsung (seventh century), Ma-hoen and Fei-shin (fifteenth century), Ibne Batuta (fourteenth century) from Africa, Nicola Kanti (fifteenth century) and Ceasar the Frederik (sixteenth century) from Venice, Verthema, an Italian in the sixteenth century, Barbosa and Sebastin Manric (sixteenth century) from Portugal, Travernier and Bernier from France (seventeenth century) and Queen Elizabeth-the First\'ambassador Ralf Fish.</br></br>

        Etymologically, the word Bangladesh is derived from the cognate Vanga which was first mentioned in Aitarey Aranyaka, a Hindu scripture composed between 500 BC and 500 AD.

    ]]>
 </string>
```

And in your activity set your text in this way:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html)));
```

Comment: add breaks and paragraphs tags as per your required formatting.

Comment: Actually i can do that by adding \n and \t manually
My question : is there any way to keep the formatting programatically/anyother way without adding anything(</br> for your answer) manually as my data set is big?